# Transferring values from one form to another

Tags: c#

I am having trouble figuring out this fix to this.

I want to transfer the username that is entered in the "Login Form" onto the "Redirect Form" where it says 'Thank you for logging in (USERNAME)'.

Pictures are here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikX4o.png

I want whatever i type in the Username on the first form, after clicking on the Login button, to be transferred to the Redirect form and where it says "Abdullah" changes to the username that was in the login form.

Thank you

This is the code in the Login Form

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Users singleResult = Data.UsersL.Find(usr => usr.UserName == txtUsername.Text && usr.PassWord == txtPassword.Text);

        if (singleResult == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
        if (singleResult.Permitted == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Im sorry, you are not authorized");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User is authorized");
            FrmRedirect f1 = new FrmRedirect();  
            f1.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: Did you wrote any code?

Comment: Use a static variable for storing the name, so that you can get it from any forms.

Comment: @RagingBull Could you be more specific, new to coding and such, if you could help me with some code would REALLY appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the easiest way would be to handle over the data directly when instantiating the form. The previous solution is imo not the best as I would always avoid static classes, if you don't need them.

You have some options:

1. Create a constructor with a parameter that you pass the argument to
2. Create a property

   FrmRedirect f1 = new FrmRedirect(name);
   f1.ShowDialog();

where your constructor would be:

```
public FrmRedirect(string name)
{
     lblTitle.Text = "Thank you for logging in " + name;
}
```

Otherwise if your form would have already been opened, you should consider using events with custom **EventArgs** for transferring data between the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class in the project:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static string Name = "";
}
```

Set the value of this variable from the login form (on the click event of login button):

```
MyClass.Name = txtUsername.Text;
```

Now you can use this variable anywhere in your project.

In Redirect form:

```
lblTitle.Text = "Thank you for logging in " + MyClass.Name;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a static class for that here. It would be more convenient to handle over the data directly when instantiating the form.

Comment: @Trade: This is what we do usually in our projects. Because, username might be needed in several forms in the applications. Do you prefer to send it to all of them through constructors? It will be hell of a way. Using the method in my answer, it is pretty simple. You just have to use `MyClass.Name`, as simple as that.

Comment: @RagingBull That's another situation. In this case the name is handled over once and the constructor is the easiest way to do it. It is not necessary to create a static class for that here.

Comment: @Trade: For sending to one form, constructor might be easy. But when someone is trying to learn, he should be learning the methods used in standard applications, not some tricks to solve the current problem.

Comment: @RagingBull You could mention it, yes, but in this case it isn't necessary at all. And in a standard application you would handle also with the constructor, if you do it once. It's depending on the situation and what you do. That is in fact the thing the should be said, if somebody is learning.